# Resume ProgressBar in Activity from current running Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-progressbar, onresume

I created an Android app that can downloading file. 
I used [Groundy library](http://casidiablo.github.com/groundy/) to support the service. And I created the NotiThread from [this](http://www.mirwing.com/2012/01/android-progressbar-notification.html) (but I edited it for support my requirement)..
Here is my Activity code ...

```
public class PacksActivity extends Activity {

private Context context;
private RelativeLayout download;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private NotiThread notification;
private String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.packs);

    context = this;
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    download = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.label_circle);
    download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File dest = new File(context.getFilesDir(), new File(url).getName());
            if(!dest.exists()){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notification = new NotiThread(context);
                notification.run();
                Bundle extras = new Bundler().add(DownloadTemplate.PARAM_URL, url).build();
                Groundy.create(context, DownloadTemplate.class)
                        .receiver(mReceiver)
                        .params(extras)
                        .queue();
            }
        }
    });
}

private ResultReceiver mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Groundy.STATUS_PROGRESS:
                int progress = resultData.getInt(Groundy.KEY_PROGRESS);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if((progress % 10) == 0)notification.progressUpdate(progress);
                break;
            case Groundy.STATUS_FINISHED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success Download file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notification.completed();
                break;
            case Groundy.STATUS_ERROR:
                Toast.makeText(context, resultData.getString(Groundy.KEY_ERROR), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notification.completed();
                break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

This is my NotiThread class

```
public class NotiThread extends Thread {

private NotificationManager mNoti = null;

private final Context mContext;
private final int mUnique;
private Notification noti;

public NotiThread(Context context) {
    super("NotiThread");
    mContext = context;
    mNoti = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mUnique = 1;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

    noti = new Notification(R.drawable.icon1024, "title", System.currentTimeMillis());
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_title, "title");
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.noti_progress, 100, 0, false);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_text, "0%");
    noti.contentView = contentView;

    noti.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, mContext.getClass()), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    mNoti.notify(mUnique, noti);
}

public void progressUpdate(int percentageComplete) {
    noti.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.noti_progress, 100, percentageComplete, false);
    noti.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_text, percentageComplete + "%");
    mNoti.notify(mUnique, noti);
}

public void completed()    {
    mNoti.cancel(mUnique);
}
}
```

And this is GroundyTask class

```
public class DownloadTemplate extends GroundyTask {

public static final String PARAM_URL = "com.app.service.PARAM_URL";

@Override
protected boolean doInBackground() {
    try {
        String url = getParameters().getString(PARAM_URL);
        File dest = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), new File(url).getName());
        DownloadUtils.downloadFile(getContext(), url, dest, DownloadUtils.getDownloadListenerForTask(this));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I want to ask, how to resume activity to update the ProgressBar from the current running service when enter to the activity and from notification?

Comment: That is exactly my question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the service is still running when coming back to your activity. How I do it is I use a singleton Network class. Here I define the callback object that is used in the Groundy create function. This singleton also keeps track of the state of the task (running, or not running when cancelled, finished or failed). When the activity is created again, this singleton class still exists so the progress callback is still being fired. The only thing you need to make sure is to re-register your listeners from the new activity to the existing singleton. Here's a simple example..

Singleton class:

```
public static SingletonClass getInstance(Object o) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SingletonClass();
    }
    if (o instanceof OnProgressListener) {
        progressListener = (OnProgressListener) o;
     }
    ...
    return instance;
}
```

Callback object:

```
    public Object callbackObject = new Object() {
       @OnProgress(YourGroundyTask.class)
       public void onProgress(@Param(Groundy.PROGRESS) int progress) {
        if (progressListener != null){
            progressListener.onDownloadProgress(progress);
        }
       }
       ...
```